# Manipulate integers to zero

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, integer

## Objective

Given a nonempty unordered list of **positive** integers, decide whether they can be added, negated, or multiplied to yield a single zero. Each given number must be used exactly once.

There is a taboo. Do not multiply zero to anything. Adding zero to anything is OK.

## Examples

### Truthy

```
List, Solution
[1,1], 1-1
[1,1,2], 2-1-1
[2,3,5], 2+3-5
[2,3,6], 2*3-6
[1,2,3,4], 2-1+3-4
[1,1,3,4], 1*1+3-4
[2,2,3,4], 2*3-2-4
[1,1,2,2,2], (2-1*1)*2-2
```

### Falsy

```
[1]
[1,2]
[2,3,4]
[1,3,3,4] ((3-3)*1*4 isn't valid because multiplication by zero is taboo)
```

Comment: Suggest truthy cases where brackets are unavoidable

Comment: This is essentially [24 game](https://code.golf/24-game)

Comment: `[1,1,2,2,2]` can be solved with `1+1-2+2-2` without parens. A better example might be `[1,2,3,9] -> (1+2)*3-9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 56 bytes

```
⊞υＡＦυＦＬιＦκ«≔⟦§ιλ§ικ⟧θＦΦ⟦ΠθΣθ↔↨θ±¹⟧∨μν⊞υ⊞ＯΦι∧⁻ξκ⁻ξλμ»¬⌈⌊υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8/a8MwEMXn@FPceAfXwVkzuUMh0CSGjsaDYqu2iCzF@lMMpZ/dkUxTyg2PH7x7964bheus0OtaRz9iZDiaewxIdCg@rQOMBJu@SzOEERX98o3gu9hV3qvBYFOFo@nlgopBE8M/vFHLMKe03bb2pnSQDpva2T52Aefk/ojTptXVWx2DxFfhJc4MZzmIhCVRDrk4nBhMAnh2zXq5SyeCdc/odLMyPZ6UiR6XXIDhD3TaZpjydz9F7ZQJeLYBT2JRU2qRfJvGZKPDujZNySXv87Tt@vKlHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υＡＦυ
```

Start a breadth-first search with the initial list of integers.

```
ＦＬιＦκ«
```

Loop over the indices of every pair of integers in the list.

```
≔⟦§ιλ§ικ⟧θ
```

Extract the integers.

```
ＦΦ⟦ΠθΣθ↔↨θ±¹⟧∨μν
```

Loop over the sum and the absolute difference, and also the product, if it is nonzero.

```
⊞υ⊞ＯΦι∧⁻ξκ⁻ξλμ
```

Remove the integers from the list and add the new value, then add the new list to the list of lists to search.

```
»¬⌈⌊υ
```

Check whether a zero result was obtained.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 101 bytes

Returns **0** or **1**.

```javascript
f=a=>a==0|a.some((p,i)=>a.some((q,j)=>i<j&&[p+q,p-q,p*q||f].some(v=>f(q,q[i]=v),q=a.filter(_=>j--))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDNboQgEMfvPgXZwwZZcAu6JpsWb@0T9EZJQ7bS1VjxqyZNfHeLol3bS4eQMPOb@c8wuepVe2myqiOleUvHUXPFE8X53aCC1nykEFY4821o8WqcWy97yPd7UR1qXBF7UT0MWrqMnifaZtUik7z3cc1VoLOiSxv4ypOcEN/aeDFla4o0KMw73Inn5rO7fsmdf@8JICimEoPFjkdACfXAHMZsBTbMyAIYDvFpCw4hOa0g3gIUkthJTShyyEnZmmjtskUU/SD2t8rKsVvVhOf5LIJWEVEfMcImHOHYnrNcB4lRTCJ09mSgTfOoLleoAE/AdikaKrsnz/u1qJdSPKmivW1K4uU77rHM52Lh7PzfY/wG)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = a =>            // a[] = input array
a == 0 |            // success if a[] == [0]
a.some((p, i) =>    // for each value p at index i in a[]:
  a.some((q, j) =>  //   for each value q at index j in a[]:
    i < j &&        //     abort if i >= j
    [               //     otherwise, compute:
      p + q,        //       addition
      p - q,        //       subtraction
      p * q         //       multiplication, whose result is ...
      || f          //       ... invalidated if it's 0
    ].some(v =>     //     for each value v in the above array:
      f(            //       do a recursive call:
        q,          //         pass q[]
        q[i] = v    //         with q[i] = v
      ),            //       end of recursive call
      q =           //       initialize q[] to ...
      a.filter(_ => //       ... a copy of a[] with ...
        j--         //         ... the j-th element removed
      )             //       end of filter()
    )               //     end of some()
  )                 //   end of some()
)                   // end of some()
```

Comment: It fails for `[4,6,6,9] 6*6-4*9` (suggested by @l4m2)

Comment: @Mukundan314 Thanks for reporting this. Should be fixed. (It was a generic bug, not directly related to this specific test case.)

Comment: Neel Shukla: please stop editing this post. Multiplying by 0 is not allowed as per the challenge rules, so `1,2,2,9` is falsy. You can't do `(9-1)*(2-2)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 98 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,a,b)=>[b]<f?x.some((t,i)=>f(x.filter(_=>i--),t,a))|x==a:[a+b,a-b,a*b||f].some(y=>f([...x,y]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5fC8IgFMXf@yRaV2F/GhS5PsgYoUvDWDM2CQf77ubqMY3Dffkdzrnnzl986kb9tGQwV@m9YsgBB4FZ3Yj2pM6OTuYhEbKgA1PIUaV7K0d0YbUmBIMFjvHiGOPHhu8EcBJuK5ZFtd/ovMYaSqmDucXYd2aYTC9pb24oGBlkgW5@KeQRnkMB@wSvoj2rUyY@xJ08mSmhCjrE2uK/E0vje4o/ez5aPf8G)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 106 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,a,b)=>1/b?f([...x,a+b])|f([...x,a-b])|a*b*f([...x,a*b]):x+x?x.some((t,i)=>f(x.filter(_=>i--),t,a)):!a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5BDoIwEEX33sLdFKY1gLogAQ5iiGmxNSVIDTSmC@9ey0I2Fpf//cz70/MXn7tJPy0dzU16rypwyFGQqs4OolFwYYwFkoqWvNdEl8QTkawkCaR0qWscm81DAljUwaHAMaUHKye4VrWmlKBFTki5574z42wGyQZzh@DJMGsJ2f1SzCM8xwJPG/wc9SzNcWMh3uR/buITGw/FFcW38R8)

Comment: Your 96-byte version disagrees with your 106-byte version for e.g. `[2,2,2,2,2]`.

Comment: @Arnauld Should be fix if no stringified number is smaller than `"("`

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 292 bytes

```py
lambda v:0 in[*f(v)]
R=range
def f(v):
 k=[v]
 for i in R(len(v)):
  for j in R(i+1,len(v)+1):
   if j-1>1 and j-i<len(v):
    for t in f(v[i:j]):k+=[v[:i]+[t]+v[j:]]
 for i in k:
  if len(i)==1:yield i[0];continue
  if(V:=i[0]*i[1]):k+=[[V,*i[2:]]]
  for I in[-1,1]:k+=[[i[0]+I*i[1],*i[2:]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NT4MwGMfvfIrnNqAloaDGVOtxya477FJ7wAH6ABZCkGSfHtsyJ4LhQn//t7a7DB@tTh@7ftqL16nJPt/yDEYeA2oZlv4YKO8o@ky/F15elGAJ96AWclQelG0PaJxw9JtCG8lqjlYzRcLorBDmNMASqoi9MMh0bv7weZad5pKDTZoZibxSAa@JmZIcFZGDIqOsuFoO1zZoOm0LBkIwfsGiyQFlrJ7OrR5QfxXO4p@4sDREya698kTNKTGN6nrtg312xChTs8EGyMFFbtap61EP/t6X1hcE3vJMkz8koSm935CHVcqyu03TmiU3H6wm7fdr3UW7MImXZeu5zYXW4@m/4z870zc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>387</del> 371 bytes

A port of [@Ajax1234's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271725/110802) in scala.

Saved 16 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

---

Golfed version (371 bytes). [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZHNTsJAEMfDlaeY9GB26Qe0oDGFknghMcGT8UQ4rNCSKbUl7VoDTZ_ECx704hvxCD6F29aWoLTxtDPz_-18vn5EC-ax_udMUv3ghYW-ND-0voJH115wuGPoQ9IGWNoOPAmHsHAVmXAThmw7u-ch-qs5NeHBRw5WTgJsRJR7PpmQKUac6ArolNI6SQGjRjUU6CtwWard7ln9qj53AQwaizcAxv8yFNifISRVgg4YvfM_G5pu3MagdhvFLI2IUTVblUnb78_cUa8PrSg78YTEZobObn0-p5ZDYqotAp-Ly0dEjJIxzgljTtluW7lWEjMP1sdgpcytMiZyyjJxgjDBkUp6wAOItQh3tqpTjQek5OjQFTrK-pH4paMD7ti4cFUcFfqQj1TRnhZ5uLAJKi6l6RZtbwllrKegqJ63wYURa8sw2BDBDdea4zF-xzYJWmN0COYZLUunVeMoVkBtL7KTk5CC4p5KZnUyK5sOi7wGNeUckXOh9NTcS9O02P3bz7vfF-83)

```scala
def F(v:List[Int])=f(v).contains(0)
def f(v:List[Int]):LazyList[Int]={val k:LazyList[List[Int]]=LazyList(v)++(for{i<-(0 to v.size-1).to(LazyList);j<-(i+1 to v.size).to(LazyList);if j>2&j-i<v.size;t<-f(v.slice(i,j))}yield v.slice(0,i)++List(t)++v.drop(j));k.flatMap{i=>if(i.size==1)LazyList(i(0))else{LazyList(i(0),i(1),i(0)*i(1))++(i.drop(2):+(i(0)+i(1))):+(i(0)-i(1))}}}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVS7TsMwFF2Y-hVHCCGbJqEND6GKVoIBCQkmRJeKwbROcWucKjGRCsqXsLDAR_E1uLYTno0YEuXec-7rXMfPb_mYSbb38vL6oJPw6H1jK72d8bHGJRMKTy1gwhPcG4OwbJr3cJJlbDm60plQ0xvaw7USGn3LBBbGq6UiZ-RC5Jp0A3QppeugAPEaNA6wF-CgQnd3_8QP1-d2hP3G4g2E-H8ZHO3XEJvhJnYQd_6ObGi6UY39tWq4WRopcd1sXaZs-eWekaKHFWt0rvRqpadpKjlTZqsJKWg0TpU2-8-JGciHJD9DLtjjsrbr41AwifkXsGasKJXXlEC7DZKkmQ8DBI5DkA4elBYSRSS5muo7GumUVGHUU2eWKtBGFzpt5orE0ENDHJhne9saplQd5Gl6ldKMGOVSjDkRAWZe1xJLweUEFdQJIGz3dhBtP4tokqULUoXY1zxKJNOXbIEnU7A_-OyHCF8b_b75WT5VEdEdZ5Oqcy5zXqvjhB0aDR3JHDZhzlWN_sgRWDTA0OksXH8xRc9aNkPbcug3X-h8Pm3Zqt5lq3SXhb8zqrvjAw)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(F(List(1, 1)))
    println(F(List(1, 1, 2)))
    println(F(List(2, 3, 5)))
    //println(F(List(2, 3, 6)))
    println(F(List(1, 2, 3, 4)))
    println(F(List(1, 1, 3, 4)))
    println(F(List(2, 2, 3, 4)))
    println(F(List(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)))
    println("-" * 20)
    println(F(List(1)))
    println(F(List(1, 2)))
    println(F(List(2, 3, 4)))
    //println(F(List(1, 3, 3, 4)))
    //println(F(List(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)))
  }

  def F(v: List[Int]): Boolean = f(v).contains(0)

  def f(v: List[Int]): LazyList[Int] = {
    val k: LazyList[List[Int]] = LazyList(v) ++ (for {
      i <- (0 until v.length).to(LazyList)
      j <- (i + 1 to v.length).to(LazyList)
      if j - 1 > 1 && j - i < v.length
      t <- f(v.slice(i, j))
    } yield v.slice(0, i) ++ List(t) ++ v.drop(j))
    
    k.flatMap { i =>
      if (i.length == 1) LazyList(i.head)
      else {
        val V = i.head * i(1)
        LazyList(i.head, i(1), V) ++ (i.drop(2) :+ (i.head + i(1))) :+ (i.head - i(1))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [371 bytes](https://pastebin.com/EeVTsnYZ)